# Sending Multiple Checkbox Values in Form Post Request

Tags: php, html

Currently I have a form that contains multiple checkboxes that you may check as many as you want.

The problem is that when I send them through my form to PHP, PHP only gets the last checkbox's value that was checked. How do I get all and store them as an array or some other way?

HTML:

```
<form action="php/submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="spacing">
    <a class="applicationLabel">Position(s) interested in:</a><br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="Project Manager" /> Project Manager<br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="Content Developer" /> Content Developer<br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="Graphic Designer" /> Graphic Designer<br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="Digital Media Creator & Storyteller" /> Digital Media Creator & Storyteller<br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="Programmer" /> Programmer<br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="Server Engineer/Technician" /> Server Engineer/Technician<br>
    <input name="position" type="checkbox" value="User Experience Designer" /> User Experience Designer<br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$positions = $_POST['position'];
echo $positions;
?>
```

The output that I get is the value of the last checkbox that was pressed. The $positions variable only holds one value and not all. How do I make it hold all that were checked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `name="position"` to `name="position[]"` in all of your `input` tags and then handle the `$_POST['position']` variable as an array.

Use `var_dump($_POST)` to see what data will be sent to PHP after you fix the `name` attributes in your HTML.

Comment: Awesome! If I wanted to insert the array of data into a MySQL database column how would I do that? What I have now is: INSERT INTO `applications` (positions) VALUES ('".$positions."')

Comment: @Nicolas no problem... but for future reference, you should serialize the array so it can be stored into the single column, or turn it into some kind of scalar value. For better database flexibility, you could store each value in a One-To-Many table relationship.